# Как сбросить GTID_EXECUTED

Tags: mysql, репликация

Пытался настроить репликации в mysql 5.7. Но что-то пошло не так и решил сделать все заново. Ввожу `RESET MASTER;` ожидая что он сбросит значение глобальной переменной `GTID_EXECUTED`. (Если не сбросить, то не получится влить свежий дамп). Проверяю командой:

```
show global variables like 'GTID_EXECUTED';
```

результат:

```
'gtid_executed', '0a27ca6d-c476-11e7-a316-901b0e962399:1-279330'
```

Других способов сбросить это значение не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: Выключить/включить gtid_mode, например? `gtid_mode=off|on`. Цитата из мануала: `The values of gtid_purged and gtid_executed are not persistent while gtid_mode=off. Therefore, after changing gtid_mode to OFF, once all binary logs containing GTIDs are purged, the values of these variables are lost. `

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, путём отключения/включения `gtid_mode`, так как после выключения, переменные `gtid_purged` и `gtid_executed` будут сброшены.

> The values of gtid_purged and gtid_executed are not persistent while gtid_mode=off. Therefore, after changing gtid_mode to OFF, once all binary logs containing GTIDs are purged, **the values of these variables are lost**. (c) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-gtids.html